# Add relationship to event participants

Tags: civievent, relationships

Is there a quick and simple way of adding a relationship to the participants of a particular event all at once? When we have people register for any event, we would like to add a specific relationship to another contact of a different contact type to each of those contacts at once. Naturally, we can do this one by one by going into the contacts details but this is slow. I tried using Find Participants, listing the participants for a specific event and then clicking the Action button in the hope that one of the options would be 'Add relationship' but it wasn't there.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to SE!

Using "Find Participants" gives you the Participant records (the record of a contact's participation in an event), but to create Relationships you want the Contact records.

Go to `Search > Advanced Search`, open up the `Events` section and add whatever parameters you want there, and then `Search`.  After you have selected some/all of the results, the `Actions` dropdown show `Add relationship` actions

Comment: Hi Aiden. Thanks so much for your help with this. Much appreciated.